# Could not reload Apache because of config test fail looking for a host files it no longer exists

Tags: apache2

I use to have like 700 virtual hosts on my server. Half of them where not active so I decide to disable and remove them by deleting their `.conf` files.

Now when I try to reload Apache I got the following:

```
* Reloading web server apache2
 * 
 * The apache2 configtest failed. Not doing anything.
Output of config test was:
[Fri Apr 10 17:25:28.166779 2020] [so:warn] [pid 15373] AH01574: module headers_module is already loaded, skipping
apache2: Syntax error on line 226 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Could not open configuration file /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/thepopulardesign.pe-le-ssl.conf: No such file or directory
Action 'configtest' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
```

Similar when I try to get a certificate for a new domain I got:

```
Error while running apache2ctl configtest.
Action 'configtest' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.

[Fri Apr 10 17:30:28.227920 2020] [so:warn] [pid 15779] AH01574: module headers_module is already loaded, skipping
apache2: Syntax error on line 226 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Could not open configuration file /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/thepopulardesign.pe-le-ssl.conf: No such file or directory
```

Note that thepopulardesign.pe is one the domains I have delete.

What can I do?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the output of `cat /etc/apache2/apache2.conf`

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like you may have deleted the host configurations from the `/etc/apache2/sites-available/` folder, but not the symlinks to them in `/etc/apaches/sites-enabled`.

Double-check whether there are still symlinks to non-existent virtual hosts in `sites-enabled`, and erase them as needed.